# How does surjectivity imply the equality of the image set to the codomain?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Graphically, it seems that surjective functions have the codomain and the image equal to one another. But, working only with the definition of surjectivity, I can only understand how the all quantifier in "$\forall y\in Y \exists x\in X: f(x) = y$" implied the entirety of the set $Y$ and not necessarily the entirety of $X$ to actually form $f(X) = Y$, and therefore have the supposed equality proven. Am I wrong to assume such equality? Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can only understand how the all quantifier in "$\forall y \in Y \exists x \in X \colon f(x) = y$" implied the entirety of the set $Y$ and not necessarily the entirety of $X$ to actually form $f(X)=Y$

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say here, but I assume you seem to see that the image of $X$ under $f$ is a subset of $Y$, and the converse is the problem?

---

*Note: I assume 0 is a natural number.*

A function takes an element in the *domain* and maps it to a unique element in the *codomain*. The *image* of the domain under the function is the set of points that the function actually maps to. For example, define $$f \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$ where $$f(n) = n$$ Then $\mathbb{N}$ is the domain, $\mathbb{Z}$ is the codomain. What is the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under $f$? We have to work a little bit to figure this out: take any element in $\mathbb{Z}$, $m$ say. If there is a natural number $n$ such that $f(n)=m$ then $m$ is in the image; otherwise it isn't. So, for our choice of $f$, the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under $f$ is just $\mathbb{N}$. No negative integer, however, is hit by $f$. The negative integers are in the codomain, but not in the image. Clearly, the image of $f$ is a subset of the domain. This map is not surjective.

Now, with domain and codomain as above, what if we define $g(0) = 0, g(2n+1)=n+1, g(2n)=-n$? You can verify that this function $g$ maps 0 to 0, 1 to 1, 2 to -1, 3 to 2, 4 to -2, etc. What is special about this function is that the image equals the codomain: indeed, any integer is hit by $g$ this time. Or, in other words, no integer can avoid the image of $g$.

This latter map is an example of a surjective map. You can think of being surjective as "the image covers the codomain" -- I always think of a blanket: if the domain is "large" enough and the domain can be "stretched" by $f$ so that it covers the codomain, then it is surjective. (For an example where the domain is "too small", take any finite set as the domain, the codomain still $\mathbb{Z}$; no function will be able to stretch this finite domain to cover an infinite set. So there exists no surjection.)

---

Visually, I always find diagrams like this helpful (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain):

[image: Red is the domain, blue the codomain, yellow the image]

Here, red is the domain, blue the codomain, yellow the image. So, your intuition is right! If $f$ can stretch the domain far enough, then it is surjective; that equates to covering the blue codomain with the yellow blanket.

---

Now for a proof, we assume $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective. Write $\mathrm{Im}(X)$ for the image of $X$ under $f$. We show $\mathrm{Im}(X) = Y$.

- It follows from the definition that the image is a subset of the codomain, so there is nothing to do to show that $\mathrm{Im}(X) \subset Y$.
- For the other direction, suppose $y \in Y$. We have to show $y$ is in the image of $f$ under $X$. Since $f$ is surjective, there is an $x$ in $X$ with $f(x) = y$. The image of $X$ under $f$ is exactly the set of points $f(z)$ for all $z \in X$. So, in particular, $f(x) \in \mathrm{Im}(X)$. But we established that $f(x) = y$, and so $y$ is in the image of $X$ under $f$. As $y$ was chosen arbitrarily, we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I meant that I didn't understand how $f(X) = Y$ can be derived from the definition of surjectivity, since the all quantifier relates to $Y$.

Comment: @Jobran Not all quantifiers relate to $Y$, only the leading one does. That shows that surjectivity really is a property of both the domain and the codomain. You can change the domain of $g$ to any proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$, for example, and $g$ will fail to be surjective. Likewise, if you properly extend the codomain of $g$ (to the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ for example), surjectivity fails, too.

Answer (score 0):

If f(X) = Y, then for all y in Y, exists x with f(x) = y.

Assume for all y in Y, exists x with f(x) = y.
Thus Y subset f(X).  Clearly, f(X) subset Y.
Consequently f(X) = Y.

I have no idea how to show any of this graphically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to understand why $f(X) \subset Y$ und $Y \subset f(X)$ given that the all quantifier relates to Y.

Comment: @Jobran  For all x in X, f assigns a value in Y.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $y \in Y$ lies in the image of $X$ if and only if $\exists x \in X : f(x) = y$.

For arbitrary $y$, let's call this statement $\phi(y)$. $\phi$ is true for a particular $y$ if and only if it lies in the image.

Now it should be clear that your definition of surjectivity is just $\forall y \in Y \phi(y)$. This is exactly the statement that *all* elements of the codomain are in the image: $Y \subseteq F(X)$. Clearly we have $F(X) \subseteq Y$ and so $F(X) = Y$.

---

The reason the universal quantifier ($\forall$) refers to $Y$ only is because surjectivity of $f$ is a statement about the images of elements in $X$, and hence about elements in the set $Y$.

However, if you like, we can rephrase the definition to talk about elements of $X$:

$f$ is surjective if (and only if) $\not \exists y \in Y$ such that $\forall x \in X f(x) \neq y$.